# Postgresql create trigger to operate on shard

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers

I am a bit weak in the area of databases and more specifically with respect to triggers and stored procedures. Our current database is sharded and each shard is distinguished by a schema. Each tenant belongs in a specified shard. In order to operate on a specific tenant we first have to go to the database and select which shard the tenant is on based on the tenant id. After getting the shard id we are then able to create a query to operate on a specific tenant. We know how to create the . based on the shard id.

My question is how can we bybass making a request to the database just for the shard id and create a trigger on select, insert, update, and delete for each statement so that we can select the correct shard id and therefore correct schema to query on? Is this even possible? Is a trigger even necessary?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible with triggers, and there is no trigger for a select statement. A possible workaround would be to create a user with permissions to execute a procedure/function which will do the "logic" and remove all other permissions from that user. I would not recommend it though.

Comment: @JorgeCampos What about adding a stored procedure to return the shard id and using that information to do something like this: `select * from getSchemaShardId(tenantId).email_accounts` where `getSchemaShardId` is a stored procedure and I would use the return result as the namespace of the query?

Comment: This would only work through dynamic SQL. You can't use a function to return the name of the schema/namespace. You can however create a function that will return a table/recordset of the table you want from that tenantId. something like `select * from returnTableFunction('tableName', tenantId)` and in your function you will dynamic create a query like `select * from tenantId.paramTablename` and return it as table. Though this will have a huge impact in performance overall

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-function-returns-a-table/

Comment: I think that the logical thing to do would be setting `search_path` based on the user right after you connect.